# Significato di "budello"

Tags: etymology, regional

Ho vissuto per dieci anni in Toscana e l'espressione "ir budello di tu' ma" e le sue varianti non mi sono perciò nuove. Per quelli che non dovessero conoscere l'espressione, penso di non sbagliarmi troppo nel sostenere che sia equivalente al senese "la tu' mamma maiala", la cui semantica è piuttosto chiara.

Nonostante ciò, non mi sono mai chiesto in che modo "budello" sia arrivato a significare "prostituta" (per non usare termini volgari). Qualcuno ne sa qualcosa?

Comment: Io non sono toscano e qui, pur cogliendo l'intento non esattamente amichevole di un'espressione così, non me ne sono chiari i dettagli. Siamo sicuri che il senso letterale sia di dare della prostituta alla madre dell'interlocutore? Da esterno avrei pensato che si stesse parlando delle parti intime della medesima, così come in altre parti di Italia si impreca riferendosi allo “sticchio” o alla “fessa” delle parenti. D'altronde la sineddoche per cui le parti intime stanno per tutta la donna non sarebbe rara: “un gran pezzo di fica” etc.

Comment: Budello,  nel senso di parti delle interiora, è usato anche in Veneto come termine offensivo (bueo/buea) . L'idea è quella di materiale di scarto che viene usato come cibo per animali o gettato via, da cui la natura irrispettosa del termine.

Comment: Budello [folklore a parte :) ] è semplicemente il *singolare* di budella. Riferimento: [Budello Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/budello/).

Comment: @Tyler: Questa non è una risposta alla domanda, eslukas chiaramente conosce il significato letterale della parola *budello*, gli interessa l'origine dell'espressione *ir budello di tu' ma*.

Comment: il termine budello è inteso come prostituta... pertanto "ir budello di tu ma" vuol dire: la put...na di tua madre

Comment: A Firenze c'è un locale che si chiama Budellino. Avevo un professore che quando facevamo chiasso ci chiamava budelli. Che significato hanno i due termini?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Liguria il budello è il centro storico delle città di mare, ad esempio il famoso "budello di Alassio", caratterizzato da vie strette e non molto illuminate dal sole. 
Nel contesto da te riportato sembra riferirsi ad un espressione colorita per definire le parti intime della mamma.

Comment: Se, come ritengo anch'io, c'entrano le parti intime, penserei più al senso letterale di “budello”, cioè “[tratto del tubo intestinale](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/budello/)” etc. che non al modo in cui in Liguria designano i vicoli...

Comment: Sono d'accordo, era solo per rimarcare che il termine può avere anche un altro significato

Answer (score 3):

*Budello* indica l'intestino, e dato che l'orifizio anale non è altro che la terminazione inferiore del grosso intestino... lascio al lettori la definitiva comprensione dell'espressione!

Answer (score 2):

*Budello* non è un termine toscano ma Livornese che significa *puttana*. È un'offesa. Io son toscana e sto a Firenze e qui non si usa, si dice *grullo*, ovvero scemo.

Comment: Benvenuta su Italian.SE! Mi sono permesso di modificare la risposta per rimuovere il maiuscolo (che è considerato sgarbato in generale su Internet) e migliorare un po' la grammatica.

Answer (score 1):

Budello non significa puttana ma qualcosa di sporco e sgraziato, come l'intestino appunto. A Milano si dice di una donna non avvenente, appunto.

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian SE!

Comment: L'OP tuttavia sembra sapere di sicuro il significato dell'espressione, almeno in Toscana. Forse una differenza regionale?

Answer (score 0):

Questo reperto ci spiega l'origine dell'aggettivo "budello" tutt'oggi usato in Toscana per definire una prostituta o comunque una donna di facili costumi, associando alla sua figura il budello animale, usato per confezionare i preservativi di quei tempi, il cui uso era indispensabile, al fine di evitare di contrarre malattie sessualmente trasmissibili[image]

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE e grazie del tuo contributo! Potresti indicare la fonte di questa informazione, per favore?

Answer (score -1):

Sono livornese doc, dal sangue lontano della primula rossa (si quello che rubava, scappava sui tetti, i carabinieri a rincorrerlo ma non lo prendevano mai)
Il termine "budello di tu ma" deriva da un misto delle vostre deduzioni, il termine budello deriva dalla parte dell'intestino di scarto, qualcosa di grezzo e poco decoroso dato che stiamo parlando di interiora di bestia dove di certo non ci passa acqua santa.
Viene sostituito raramente dai dispregiativi come "budellone" o "farda" (una puttana enorme).
"Sei'na farda" valida anche come provocazione "amichevole" ovviamente esclusivamente confidenziale tra amici UOMINI stretti, non andate a dirlo a un'amica livornese anche se è la vostra migliore amica.. altrimenti non credo che lo sarà mai più per voi ahahhahah
Ci sono molte varianti dialettali ad esempio anche "tegame di tu ma" che è una delle più utilizzate attualmente.
Porta allo stesso significato, e di conseguenza stessa offesa.
Tradotto: "la puttana della tua mamma".
Dove, attenzione, già dire "tu ma" a una persona che non conosciamo è già un termine confidenziale in quel caso da considerarsi come offesa.. quindi da prendere con le pinze data anche la vicinanza alla famosa offesa "tegame/budello di tu ma".
Spero di aver fatto chiarezza.
Un saluto dal livornese.

Comment: Per curiosità: che nesso c'è fra la Primula Rossa (personaggio francese creato da una scrittrice inglese) e Livorno?